# Error when I've executing query "Invalid object name 'sw.Switch'."

Tags: c#

I got an error when I execute a query in C#:
I use schema in SQL Server, It's name is "sw". My table name is "Switch", My select operation is properly because I can execute it in sql server without any error, But when I use it in SQLDataAdaptor I got this error:

```
Invalid object name 'sw.Switch'.
```

This is my code:

```
try
{
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from sw.Switch " , con);
ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds,"sw.Switch");
return ds;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception(ex.Message);    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's in the `sw` schema?

Comment: I'm sure, Because My query have result in SQL Server.

Comment: The user in the connection string may not have rights to select the table/view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your connection string look like?

I bet you're connecting to the master database by default instead of whatever database contains the `sw` schema.